# How to get result set from store procedure with parameter in jbdc

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, resultset

i have store procedure with 1 parameter only. I can execute the procedure like this `exec proc_name param1` in microsoft SQL server management studio and show result set that i want. But when i try in java with my code like this:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://TOSHIBA\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Perpustakaan;integratedSecurity=true";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall("{call search(?)}");
    statement.setString(1,parameter);
    ArrayList<Buku> result = new ArrayList<>();
    statement.execute();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        int tempId = rs.getInt("id");
        String tempJudul = rs.getString("judul");
        result.add(new Buku(tempId, tempJudul));
    }
    return result;
```

i get an error say 'The statement did not return a result set.' The 'parameter' in `statement.setString(1,parameter)` is String typed.

this is my store procedure code in case something is wrong

```
alter proc search
@kata varchar(255)
as
declare @tempResult table
(
    kata varchar(255)
)
declare
    @idx int,
    @katas varchar(255)

set @katas = @kata
set @idx = CHARINDEX(',',@katas,1)

while(@idx != 0)
begin
    insert into @tempResult
    select
        SUBSTRING(@katas,1,@idx-1)
    set @katas = SUBSTRING(@katas,@idx+1,100000000)
    set @idx = CHARINDEX(',',@katas,1)
end
insert into @tempResult
select
    @katas

declare @searchResult table
(
    judul varchar(255)
)
insert into @searchResult
select dbo.buku.judul
from dbo.buku cross join @tempResult
where CHARINDEX(kata, dbo.buku.judul) > 0

select 
    dbo.buku.id, sr.judul
from
    @searchResult as sr join dbo.buku
on
    sr.judul = dbo.buku.judul
group by 
    sr.judul, dbo.buku.id
order by
    COUNT(sr.judul) desc

exec search 'Games'
```

Comment: Well, I could point out about 40 things, but first try removing statement.Execute(), why do you need that when you then do .executeQuery()? Also try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of the procedure body. Some libraries interpret `done_in_proc` messages as resultsets, which might mess up the code thinking the first resultset has that column.

Comment: Can you give us an example value of `kata`. You could also alter your usp_ to be 'select 'KataValue'' then call it via code, this will force a known value to be passed. This will tell you if your app code is faulty or if it is your SQL

Comment: Wow.. the 'set nocount on' is work like charm. thank for helping. so i should use 'set nocount on' on my other similiar store procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what i do to make the statement return result set is i add `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the beginning of my store procedure.
[set nocount explanation is here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

In order to call stored procedures with callable statement you need to registerOutParameter for the expected results. Also you don't need to `executeQuery` after the `execute` becaues you don't have a query and you have already executed your statement

Try to change your code to:

```
boolean hasResults=statement.execute();

while (hasResults) {
    ResultSet rs = cStmt.getResultSet();
    int tempId = rs.getInt("id");
    String tempJudul = rs.getString("judul");
    result.add(new Buku(tempId, tempJudul));
    hasResults= cStmt.getMoreResults();        
}
```

But before that you should add the parameters you expect to the statement. Just the way you do :

```
 statement.setString(1,parameter);
 // Add out parameters here
 statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
 ....
```

I cannot be bothered to look at the procedure call right now ;) but I guess it works if you can execute it in management studio